# How to print a list of time slots 2 hours apart?

Tags: java, date

I am trying to save all the time slots within a 7 day period, starts from 10am and ends at 6pm, i.e.

```
2021-03-20 10:00:00
2021-03-20 12:00:00
2021-03-20 14:00:00
2021-03-20 16:00:00
2021-03-20 18:00:00
2021-03-21 10:00:00
```

all the way to 03/27 to an `ArrayList` and use them later in a RedBlackTree. I checked other posts and felt like I should use `LocalDateTime` class. But I couldn't figure out how to put them together.

Answer (score 2):

The following code performs the actions you stipulated in your question, i.e. starting from 20<sup>th</sup> March 2021 at 10:00 am and ending at 27<sup>th</sup> March at 6:00 pm, creates a `List` of `LocalDateTime` instances.

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Print list of time slots 2 hours apart.
 */
public class TimeSlot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 3, 20, 10, 0); // 2021-03-20 10:00:00
        LocalDateTime last = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 3, 28, 0, 0);
        List<LocalDateTime> slots = new ArrayList<>();
        while (ldt.isBefore(last)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                slots.add(ldt);
                ldt = ldt.plusHours(2);
            }
            ldt = ldt.withDayOfMonth(ldt.getDayOfMonth() + 1);
            ldt = ldt.withHour(10);
        }
        slots.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The output when running the above code is:

```
2021-03-20T10:00
2021-03-20T12:00
2021-03-20T14:00
2021-03-20T16:00
2021-03-20T18:00
2021-03-21T10:00
2021-03-21T12:00
2021-03-21T14:00
2021-03-21T16:00
2021-03-21T18:00
2021-03-22T10:00
2021-03-22T12:00
2021-03-22T14:00
2021-03-22T16:00
2021-03-22T18:00
2021-03-23T10:00
2021-03-23T12:00
2021-03-23T14:00
2021-03-23T16:00
2021-03-23T18:00
2021-03-24T10:00
2021-03-24T12:00
2021-03-24T14:00
2021-03-24T16:00
2021-03-24T18:00
2021-03-25T10:00
2021-03-25T12:00
2021-03-25T14:00
2021-03-25T16:00
2021-03-25T18:00
2021-03-26T10:00
2021-03-26T12:00
2021-03-26T14:00
2021-03-26T16:00
2021-03-26T18:00
2021-03-27T10:00
2021-03-27T12:00
2021-03-27T14:00
2021-03-27T16:00
2021-03-27T18:00
```

Refer to the [Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) trail in Oracle's Java tutorials and to the *javadoc* of class [java.time.LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

Comment: It’s a very nice answer, thank you. As a matter of taste I think I’d use `LocalDate` for iterating over the days and then `LocalDate.atTime()` for starting at 10:00 each day.